# Swift 4 Json request to php

Tags: php, json, swift, request, swift4

I need your help please.
I tried to write a json request in Xcode Swift4

Json Request to PHP:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://example.net/stock_service3.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "id=112m&name=123"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")

            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
```

And this is the including mySQL PHP Code in my web server:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("example.mysql:3306","example.net","3445432FruRjCAFk","example.net");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),TRUE);

$id= $postdata["id"];
$name = $postdata["name"];
// Store values in an array
$returnValue = array($id,$name);

// Send back request in JSON format
echo json_encode($returnValue);
// Select all of our stocks from table 'stock_tracker'
$sql ="SELECT m.*


      , ( ACOS( COS( RADIANS( $id) ) 
              * COS( RADIANS( m.latitude ) )
              * COS( RADIANS( m.longitude ) - RADIANS( $name) )
              + SIN( RADIANS($id) )
              * SIN( RADIANS( m.Latitude) )
          )
        * 6371
        ) AS distance_in_km

  FROM TankBilliger m
  HAVING distance_in_km <= 100
 ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC
 LIMIT 100";

// Confirm there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // We have results, create an array to hold the results
        // and an array to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each result
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each result into the results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Encode the array to JSON and output the results

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My mysql code works but if I want change the query with the variables I get from Swift, Swift tells me: [10788:3159246] Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x108589850) to 'NSDictionary' (0x108589288).

I want that the Query get the numbers of swift.

This is the code where my app shows the mysql Data to my iOS app and this is the code where the Error appears.

```
import Foundation

protocol FeedmodelProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class Feedmodel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {



    weak var delegate: FeedmodelProtocol!

    let urlPath = "http://example.net/stock_service3.php" //Change to the web address of your stock_service.php file

    func downloadItems() {

        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }else {
                print("stocks downloaded")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
}

    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

        var jsonResult = NSArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let stocks = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
        {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let stock = Stockmodel()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if  let Datum = jsonElement["Datum"] as? String,
                let Tankstelle = jsonElement["Tankstelle"] as? String,
                let Kraftstoff1 = jsonElement["Kraftstoff1"] as? String,
                let Preis1 = jsonElement["Preis1"] as? String,
                let Kraftstoff2 = jsonElement["Kraftstoff2"] as? String,
                let Preis2 = jsonElement["Preis2"] as? String,
                let Notiz = jsonElement["Notiz"] as? String,
                let longitude = jsonElement["longitude"] as? String,
                let latitude = jsonElement["latitude"] as? String


            {
                print (Datum)
                print(Tankstelle)
                print(Kraftstoff1)
                print(Preis1)
                print(Kraftstoff2)
                print(Preis2)
                print(Notiz)
                print(longitude)
                print(latitude)
                stock.Datum = Datum
                stock.Tankstelle = Tankstelle
                stock.Kraftstoff1 = Kraftstoff1
                stock.Preis1 = Preis1
                stock.Kraftstoff2 = Kraftstoff2
                stock.Preis2 = Preis2
                stock.Notiz = Notiz
                stock.longitude = longitude
                stock.latitude = latitude


            }

            stocks.add(stock)

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: stocks)

        })
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance :))

Code Error: `jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary`

Comment: Find the line causing the crash, because that error doesn't seem to appear in the code you showed. There is no (NS)Dictionary mention.

Comment: this is the line: jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

Comment: And any context? Because you didn't put this line nor how you got there. `jsonResult[i]` is equal to `NSNull`, so it can't be converted to a NSDictionary

Comment: Sorry, I added my swift file  right now, I am a completely newbie thats why I forgot sorry

Comment: ok I did - Larme

Comment: print `jsonResult`. On of them is null, you have to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

I think swift only connects https, I say this because I wrote a Swift 4 iOS app to go alongside an existing Android Java app (and both used a PHP server and communicated via json) and I hated having to migrate the entire server to https and migrate all the android users. There may be a way round it but I think it's a "thing" now.

Comment: You can create an iOS app that can connect to either http or https, although if you want to upload the app to the Apple App Store they require https unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: that seems right, I remember encountering when I tried to publish, 

Users need to know my answer is not wrong in principle, it's important to know in advance not have to wait until the delivery stage